# QSortFilterProxyModel limits number of records when filter is applied

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

QSortFilterProxyModel seems to limit the amount of data that can be displayed in a QTableView, but only when a filter is applied.  It would seem that the limit is data size rather than number of records, because I can fit more records into the example here than the real application where I'm seeing the behavior.

To duplicate follow these steps (in Linux, with Sqlite installed).  Code is provided below.

1. Create a new project with code provided.
2. In the directory with the executable, type: *sqlite3 testInsert.db*
3. In the sqlite prompt, type: *create table testTable(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text);*
4. Run the application and see that record 5000, testString, appears in the table view.
5. Increment the numRecords variable to 511.  (Maybe your specific numbers will vary??)
6. In the sqlite prompt, type: *drop table testTable*
7. redo step 3
8. run and see that this time record 5000 does *not* appear
9. redo step 6 (drop table), then step 3(create table).  Probably there is an easier way to clear the table, but this was working for me.
10. Near the bottom of the code, there is a call to the model's SetFilterRegExp method.  Comment that line out.
11. Run again.  In the results, scroll down to the bottom and see that record 5000 does appear.

Sample code:

```
#include <QApplication>    
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("./testInsert.db");
    db.open();


    QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(NULL, db);
    model->setTable("testTable");

    // put a bunch of dummy records into the database
    int numRecords = 510;
    for(int i=0; i<numRecords; i++)
    {
        QSqlRecord newRecord;
        QSqlField name("NAME", QVariant::String);
        name.setValue("unmatchedString");
        newRecord.append(name);
        model->insertRecord(-1, newRecord);
    }

    // put in the record we want to see
    QSqlRecord record;
    QSqlField id("ID", QVariant::Int);
    QSqlField name("NAME", QVariant::String);
    id.setValue(5000);
    name.setValue("testString");
    record.append(id);
    record.append(name);
    model->insertRecord(-1, record);
    model->select();

    QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
    proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(1);

    QRegExp filterRegExp = QRegExp("^testString$");
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(filterRegExp); // <<-- this is the line to comment out

    QTableView tableView;
    tableView.setModel(proxyModel);
    tableView.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Update: Also duplicated on another machine running Windows.  I also notice that, in the example I provided, in the case where the single record should be displaying but isn't, I can actually get it to appear by resizing the main window.  In my actual application where I first found this issue, resizing does not cause the missing records to appear.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the problem.  The only way that I could get the row to display is by adding the line:

```
proxyModel->invalidate();
```

after `tableView.show()` was called.  So far as I could tell, that shouldn't be necessary, however.